# Redirect back to default language i18n

Tags: reactjs, routes, i18next

How can I set the default language in i18n? The problem is when the user inserts none existing language in the path, the page is disappearing. The defined languages are => en, es, ar. I want to set the default language to "EN", when the user inserts in the path for example "ru" the user redirects back to English.

Here is the code for i18n.js

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

const languages = ["en", "es", "ar"]
const options = {
    loadPath: "./public/locales/{{lng}}/{{translation}}.json",
}

i18n
    .use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        fallbackLng: "en",
        debug: true,
        // lng: "en",
        whitelist: ["en", "es", "ar"],
        keySeparator: false,
        checkWhitelist: true,
        detection: {
            order: ['path', 'cookie', 'htmlTag', 'localStorage', 'subdomain'],  
            lookupFromPathIndex: 0,
            caches: ['cookie'],
            checkWhitelist: true,
        },  
    });
export default i18n;
```

Please take into consideration that LNG can't be defined here. When I use lng the translations are not working.

File: Route.js

```
export const baseUrl = () => {
    return (
        i18n.language === 'en' ? '' : '/' + i18n.language
    )
};

const Router = () => {
    const baseRouteUrl = "/:locale(es|en|ar)?";
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Options} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />

            <PrivateRoute exact path={baseRouteUrl + "/dashboard"}
                    render={(props) => {
                        return (
                            <MainLayout>
                                <DashboardPage />
                            </MainLayout>
                        )
                    }}
                />
```

File: Menu.jsx

```
<Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}>
     <Menu.Item key="1" active icon={<HomeOutlined />}>
      {
           <Link to={baseUrl() + "/dashboard"}>
               {t("DASHBOARD")}
           </Link>
       }
     </Menu.Item>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write is a `Route` with regex path at the end of all the routes to catch all and redirect.

```js
<Route
  path="/:lang([A-Za-z]{2})?/:rest*"
  render={props => {
    // availabeLanguages is an array of language codes
    if (!availableLanguages.includes(props.match.params.lang)) {
      // depending on your configuration you may need 
      // to set the language to your default language before return
      return (<Redirect to={`/${props.match.params.rest}`}/>);
    }
  }}/>
```